# How to compile FNF?

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxeflixel

when I tried to downgrade lime to the expected version (7.7) it gave me EVEN MORE errors...
I am running the command lime test windows -debug,
I've been trying to compile and mod the FNF game for like... 3 months now...
I made a haxe file called APISTUFF, and it still doesn't work!
PLEASE HELP!!!
The error I'm getting:

````
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1810: characters 22-28 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1810: characters 22-28 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1815: characters 22-28 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1815: characters 22-28 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1831: characters 24-30 : lime.utils.UInt32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1831: characters 24-30 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1836: characters 24-30 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1836: characters 24-30 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1841: characters 24-30 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:1841: characters 24-30 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeWindow.hx:143: characters 5-23 : lime._internal.backend.native.NativeOpenGLRenderContext should be lime.graphics.OpenGLES2RenderContext
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeWindow.hx:144: characters 5-23 : lime._internal.backend.native.NativeOpenGLRenderContext should be lime.graphics.WebGLRenderContext
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeWindow.hx:150: characters 6-24 : lime._internal.backend.native.NativeOpenGLRenderContext should be lime.graphics.OpenGLES3RenderContext
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeWindow.hx:151: characters 6-25 : lime._internal.backend.native.NativeOpenGLRenderContext should be lime.graphics.WebGL2RenderContext
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/utils/src/openfl/utils/ByteArray.hx:750: characters 3-30 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils._Bytes.LimeBytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/group/FlxGroup.hx:473: characters 80-91 : Type not found : ObjectClass
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4740: characters 74-75 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4740: characters 74-75 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 10-23 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 30-43 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : lime.math.ColorMatrix should be Null<lime.utils.ArrayBufferView>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/math/ColorMatrix.hx:117: characters 12-17 : ... For optional function argument 'view'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:2309: characters 36-42 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:2309: characters 36-42 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:2315: characters 36-42 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/_internal/backend/native/NativeOpenGLRenderContext.hx:2315: characters 36-42 : ... For function argument 'params'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4617: characters 63-64 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4617: characters 63-64 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4631: characters 64-65 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4631: characters 64-65 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4639: characters 66-67 : lime.utils.UInt32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4639: characters 66-67 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4655: characters 70-71 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4655: characters 70-71 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4669: characters 71-72 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4669: characters 71-72 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4678: characters 73-74 : lime.utils.UInt32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4678: characters 73-74 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4696: characters 80-81 : lime.utils.Float32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4696: characters 80-81 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4712: characters 81-82 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4712: characters 81-82 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4721: characters 83-84 : lime.utils.UInt32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4721: characters 83-84 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4757: characters 75-76 : lime.utils.Int32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4757: characters 75-76 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4767: characters 77-78 : lime.utils.UInt32Array should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/graphics/WebGL2RenderContext.hx:4767: characters 77-78 : ... For function argument 'v'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be Null<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : ... For optional function argument 'elements'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/stage3d/src/openfl/display3D/VertexBuffer3D.hx:113: characters 41-45 : ... For function argument 'data'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : lime.math.Matrix4 should be Null<lime.utils.ArrayBufferView>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/math/Matrix4.hx:235: characters 12-17 : ... For optional function argument 'view'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/media/OpenALAudioContext.hx:573: characters 3-40 : lime.media.openal.ALBuffer should be Int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/sound/src/openfl/media/Sound.hx:591: characters 37-42 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be Null<Int>
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/sound/src/openfl/media/Sound.hx:591: characters 37-42 : ... For optional function argument 'elements'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/group/FlxGroup.hx:852: characters 19-30 : Type not found : ObjectClass
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/text/harfbuzz/HBBlob.hx:47: characters 3-48 : Float should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/7,7,0/src/lime/text/harfbuzz/HBBlob.hx:56: characters 3-57 : Float should be lime.utils.DataPointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/bitmapdata/src/openfl/display/BitmapData.hx:1885: characters 45-54 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.BytePointer
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/bitmapdata/src/openfl/display/BitmapData.hx:1885: characters 45-54 : ... For function argument 'bytePointer'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/system/frontEnds/PluginFrontEnd.hx:47: characters 19-28 : Type not found : ClassType
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/4,8,1/flixel/system/frontEnds/PluginFrontEnd.hx:94: characters 20-29 : Type not found : ClassType
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:47: characters 52-57 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.Bytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:47: characters 52-57 : ... For function argument 'bytes'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:293: characters 38-43 : openfl.utils.ByteArray should be lime.utils.Bytes
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/9,0,2/packages/assets/src/openfl/utils/AssetLibrary.hx:293: characters 38-43 : ... For function argument 'bytes' ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For Lime 7.7.0 you probably should use OpenFL 8.9.7 or 8.9.6

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Could you post error? What Haxe version you have?

Comment: what version of haxe do I need?

Comment: I just realized i'm using the wrong version of haxe....

Comment: I'm getting a new error though.
`C:\Users\Charlotte\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-NT6KN1J)\Desktop\VS CBUG FULL WEEK
Error: Could not automatically setup MSVC`

Comment: I FINALLY compiled fnf, but no .exe, HELP!!

Comment: From last comment looks youd didn't setup Visual Studio, Do you fix it? 
Compiled without error and don't have .exe? Where are you looking it at?

Comment: yeah, I fixed it, I set up visual studio community, I compiled it without any errors.

Comment: Where are you looking for .exe?

Comment: in the export/debug/bin

Comment: It's versy strange, if it not compiled there should be errors in console

Comment: yeah I don't know what's happening

Comment: ```C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 10-23 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 30-43 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access```

Comment: It's just warnings, shouldn't affect